# "FileName" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the bin" when opening files from Finder

Tags: macos, catalina

I have tried re-downloading Microsoft Word, Excel multiple times and restarting before trying. However, this problem still persists.

This problem is applicable to all my documents, even PDFs too.

However, when I <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in the app itself, the document can be opened and functions normally.

The problem happens if I directly double-click or open the files from Finder.

Please advise me on how I can solve this issue.

[image: Please help, I have been facing this problem for all my documents after I restore from backup]

Answer (score 11):

Apparently the document has a quarantine flag. You can verify the same by running the following command in the Terminal.app:

`xattr <path_to_the_document>`

which should display the following:

> com.apple.quarantine

To remove the quarantine flag from a document you trust is coming from a reliable source, run the following command:

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine <path_to_the_document>`

The Terminal.app would ask you to enter your admin/login password. You can verify that the flag is removed by re-running the former command mentioned above.

Comment: Amazing! It worked!! but is there a way that work for all the documents at once?

Comment: @ChongShiHan Yes. You can specify the path (or pattern) matching all the desired filenames where `<path_to_the_document>` is specified in the command.

Comment: This method works per file, but if you edit the file or create a new one, the problem returns, and it doesn't do all files.